# Not Understanding the FU540 Boot Process

Tags: assembly, firmware, memory, static-analysis, risc-v

I'm reading the [manual](https://starfivetech.com/uploads/fu540-c000-manual-v1p4.pdf) for the SiFive FU540-C000 trying to understand the boot process, and I'm not making sense of the initial steps after power on.

I'm using `MSEL = 1111` based on the recommendation for the [software I'm booting](https://docs.sel4.systems/Hardware/hifive.html) from SD card.

> On power-on, all cores jump to 0x1004 while running directly off of the external clock input,
> expected to be 33.3 MHz. The memory at this location contains:
>
> Table 8: Reset vector ROM
>
> | Address | Contents |
> | --- | --- |
> | 0x1000 | The MSEL pin state |
> | 0x1004 | auipc t0, 0 |
> | 0x1008 | lw t1, -4(t0) |
> | 0x100C | slli t1, t1, 0x3 |
> | 0x1010 | add t0, t0, t1 |
> | 0x1014 | lw t0, 252(t0) |
> | 0x1018 | jr t0 |

This is how I've decoded the instructions.

1. `0x1004 = auipc t0, 0`

   - AUIPC uses the top 20 bits of the immediate, extends 0 to the low 12, then adds the PC value of the auipc instruction. Store in t0
   - t0 = 0x0 << 12 = 0x0 + 0x1004

| Register | Value |
| --- | --- |
| t0 | 0x1004 |
| t1 | UNDEF |
| PC (next) | 0x1008 |

2. `0x1008 = lw t1, -4(t0)`

   - Load value in memory address `(t0 - 4)`, store in t1
   - t1 = Mem[0x1004 - 4] = Mem[0x1000] = MSEL = 0b1111 = 0xF

| Register | Value |
| --- | --- |
| t0 | 0x1004 |
| t1 | 0x000F |
| PC (next) | 0x100C |

3. `0x100C = slli t1, t1, 0x3`

   - t1 is left shifted 3, store in t1
   - t1 = 0b1111 << 3 = 0b1111000 = 0x78

| Register | Value |
| --- | --- |
| t0 | 0x1004 |
| t1 | 0x0078 |
| PC (next) | 0x1010 |

4. `0x1010 = add t0, t0, t1`

   - t1 is added to t0, store in t0
   - t0 = 0x1004 + 0x0078 = 0x107C

| Register | Value |
| --- | --- |
| t0 | 0x107C |
| t1 | 0x0078 |
| PC (next) | 0x1014 |

5. `0x1014 = lw t0, 252(t0)`

   - Load value in memory address `t0 +  252`, store in t0
   - t0 = Mem[0x107C + 0xFC] = Mem[0x1178] = 0x????

| Register | Value |
| --- | --- |
| t0 | 0x???? |
| t1 | 0x0078 |
| PC (next) | 0x1018 |

6. `0x1018 = jr t0`

   - jump directly to address in t0
   - PC = 0x????

| Register | Value |
| --- | --- |
| t0 | 0x???? |
| t1 | 0x0788 |
| PC (next) | 0x???? |

The problem is that, according to the manual, MSEL = 0b1111 should jump to 0x0001_0000, doesn't mention anything about what's at 0x1178

| Base | Top | Attr. | Description Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0x0000_0000 | 0x0000_00FF |  | Reserved |
| 0x0000_0100 | 0x0000_0FFF | RWX A | Debug |
| 0x0000_1000 | 0x0000_1FFF | R X | Mode Select |
| 0x0000_2000 | 0x0000_FFFF |  | Reserved |
| 0x0001_0000 | 0x0001_7FFF | R X | Mask ROM (32 KiB) |
| 0x0001_8000 | 0x00FF_FFFF |  | Reserved |
| 0x0100_0000 | 0x0100_1FFF | RWX A | S51 DTIM (8 KiB) |

Did I interpret something wrong, or is there something else going on in this boot sequence that I'm not getting?

--EDIT 1--

In my original math I shifted the hex values left instead of binary. Going to attribute that to brain tired. It still isn't any more clear what's happening after the jump instruction.

--EDIT 2--

It was [pointed out](https://forums.sifive.com/t/whats-the-fu540-boot-sequence/5206) that I was using LW incorrectly, loading the value in the register instead of the value in memory indicated by the address in register. Updated the math and still no more clear.

--EDIT 3--

Thanks to mumbel for pointing out my incorrect use of the MSEL value. I treated as 0x1111 instead 0f 0b1111 = 0xF. I swear I know hex and binary.

Comment: I would use the tag risc-v not risc for this question

Comment: @mumbel oddly, I don't see a risc-v tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find the full memory map, but I've been told that this table can be interpreted similarly. Basically, whatever address is calculated using MSEL will have the value in the "Reset address" field. So, it's not an address to value mapping, but since it's the only variable in the algorithm, it alone determines what address will be jumped to in the final instruction, so the mapping is still valid.

Another way to look at it is that MSEL is an index into a jump table, and the base is calculated in the rest of the algorithm.

> Table 9: Target of the reset vector
>
> | MSEL | Reset address | Purpose |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 0000 | 0x0000_1004 | loops forever waiting for debugger |
> | 0001 | 0x2000_0000 | memory-mapped QSPI0 |
> | 0010 | 0x3000_0000 | memory-mapped QSPI1 |
> | 0011 | 0x4000_0000 | uncached ChipLink |
> | 0100 | 0x6000_0000 | cached ChipLink |
> | 0101 | 0x0001_0000 | ZSBL |
> | 0110 | 0x0001_0000 | ZSBL |
> | 0111 | 0x0001_0000 | ZSBL |
> | 1000 | 0x0001_0000 | ZSBL |
> | 1001 | 0x0001_0000 | ZSBL |
> | 1010 | 0x0001_0000 | ZSBL |
> | 1011 | 0x0001_0000 | ZSBL |
> | 1100 | 0x0001_0000 | ZSBL |
> | 1101 | 0x0001_0000 | ZSBL |
> | 1110 | 0x0001_0000 | ZSBL |
> | 1111 | 0x0001_0000 | ZSBL |

Answer (score 0):

MSEL is 4 pins, as in 4 bits.  This means `1111` is not 0x1111, but 0b1111 or 0xf.  So your math is correct everywhere but the 0x8888 would be 0x78 instead.

```
auipc t0, 0       <- t0 = pc + 0 => 0x1004
lw t1, -4(t0)     <- t1 = -4(0x1004) => 0xf
slli t1, t1, 0x3  <- t1 = 0xf << 3 == 0xf * 8 => 0x78
add t0, t0, t1    <- t0 = 0x1004 + 0x78 => 0x107c
lw t0, 252(t0)    <- t0 = 252(0x107c) == 0(0x1178) => ???
jr t0             <- goto ???
```

Comment: Well that leaves me equally as confused 

Comment: Heh, at least 0x1178 is mapped.  Which part is confusing or just no clue what's in memory at 0x1178?

Comment: @mumble no clue what's at that address, and the pin select guide suggests 0b1111 should jump to 0x0001_0000 for ZSBL